# How to get the option tag bigger than input

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-datalist

I have a question about the option tag inside datalist tag.

I'm creating an interface for some users and I need to make the option to be bigger than the input.

I'm using firefox, by policies of the company.
And I need to get something like Chrome in this situation:
Chrome:

[image]

As you can see, in Firefox it keeps as the size of input.
Firefox:

[image]

I like more the style of Firefox, allows me to scroll the options. But would be better if it were bigger. I can't see the entire name.

That's my code, I've added two options that aren't in the project to see how it looks:
My datalist code:

```js
/*
function buscaFuncionarios(idImput, idDatalist) {
     
     var input  = document.getElementById(idImput);
  var list   = document.getElementById(idDatalist);
  var lDados = <?php echo json_encode(!is_null($this->session->flashdata('funcionarios'))); ?>;

  if (input.readOnly == false && list.children.length == 0) { 

   if (lDados) { 
   
    var funcionarios1 = <?php echo json_encode($this->session->flashdata('funcionarios')); ?>;

    for (var indice in funcionarios1) {
     var option = document.createElement('option');
       option.label = funcionarios1[indice]["Codigo"] + " - " + funcionarios1[indice]["Nome"];
       option.value = funcionarios1[indice]["Codigo"];           
       list.appendChild(option);
    }

      }

  }

 };
*/
```

```css
.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon{
    background: white !important; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control{
 border-right:0; 
 box-shadow:0 0 0; 
 border-color:#ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button{
    border:0;
    background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='post_func2' id="post_func2" maxLength="6" list="list_func_2" onclick="//buscaFuncionarios('post_func2', 'list_func_2');" onfocus="this.select();">
    <datalist id="list_func_2" open="open">
    <option value = '1'>1-Test</option>
    <option value = '2'>2-Test</option>
    </datalist>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="button" id="post_btn_func2" onclick="printaRelatorioFuncionario('post_func2')">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>  
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes: I'm using codeigniter and bootstrap.

Thank you all and sorry for my english.

Comment: I recommend you try fixing your syntax errors first.

Comment: Could you give me some tips?

Comment: Click on "Run code snippet" above and it shows you the line number and error message.

Comment: The snippet error is about the included PHP scripts

Comment: The js it's just to you guys know where the data comes from. It's not the problem.